# JQuery Toggle Function Stopped Working PHP 7.4

Tags: php, jquery, toggle

I have searched high and low and cannot figure this one out. This is code from a page on the site and it has worked fine for years for a toggle. I just updated the website to PHP 7.4 (it was PHP 5) - and now it no longer works. The page loads - the toggle button and content show for a second then both items close and go away.

So the toggle button is no longer showing at all. I can do display:block on the button and it will show on the front end - but the toggle is not working at all.

Can anyone offer any insight into why this might be happening? Thanks!

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var adjustheight = 0;           
            var moreText = "View Session Details";
            var lessText = "Close Session";
        
            $(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');

            $("a.adjust").text(moreText);
            $(".adjust").toggle(function() {
                    $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
                    $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
                    $(this).text(lessText);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
                    $(this).text(moreText);
            });     
    });              

</script>
```

Code that pulls into the toggle......

```
echo '<div class="read-more more-less"><div class="more-block"><br/><p>'. get_the_content() .'</p>';
if( genesis_get_custom_field( 'pdf_files' ) ) echo '<div class="pdf-block"><b>Download Session Materials:</b> '.genesis_get_custom_field( 'pdf_files' ).'</div>';



    echo '<div class="details">';
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'session-level'); 
           if( $terms ){    
           $sess_nm = array();
            echo '<b>Session Level:</b> ' ;                             
                foreach($terms as $term_single) {
                 $sess_nm[] = $term_single->name;
                }           
                if( $sess_nm ){
                    $sess_nm = @array_unique($sess_nm);
                    echo join( ", ", $sess_nm ).' <br/>';
                }
            }
    
    
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'session-location');  
           if( $terms ){    
           $sess_nm = array();
    
            echo '<b>Session Location:</b> ' ;                              
                foreach($terms as $term_single) {
                 $sess_nm[] = $term_single->name;
                }           
    
                if( $sess_nm ){
                    $sess_nm = @array_unique($sess_nm);
                    echo join( ", ", $sess_nm ).' <br/>';
                }
            }       
    
    
      if( genesis_get_custom_field( 'price' ) ) echo '<b>Price:</b> '. genesis_get_custom_field( 'price' ) .' <br/>';
      if( genesis_get_custom_field( 'cle' ) ) echo '<b>CLE:</b> '. genesis_get_custom_field( 'cle' ) .' <br/>';
      if( genesis_get_custom_field( 'standards_practices' ) ) echo '<b>Standards & Practices:</b> '. genesis_get_custom_field( 'standards_practices' ) .' <br/>';   
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

Comment: PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, so has no effect on javascript, which only runs after the page is sent to the browser. You'll need to try some troubleshooting or show more of the page code.

Comment: None of the code you have shown so far, has _anything_ to do with PHP. If a PHP update broke things here, then most likely it creates a different HTML output than before, that this JavaScript is supposed to work on. So start by checking what the relevant portion of the HTML looks like.

Comment: Also, have you checked your server logs for any warnings/notices?

Comment: That is what I thought which is why I was baffled. But there are no code errors anywhere. There were a few that I had but I addressed those that were related to PHP changes. I will add the code that draws from this. Thanks guys.

Comment: I did - checked server logs and run debugger tools to find anything I could, but nothing is being triggered.

Comment: This looks like WordPress code. Have you ever debugged with WordPress? Well ...
https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: When debugging javascript, I'd ignore the PHP code entirely. View the source in the browser, and start poking at the generated code.

Comment: Yep - debugger shows nothing. Thanks Aynber -- tried that but am not seeing anything. I guess I will need to hire someone. Thanks though - thought it would be something fairly easy.